# Remove the duplicate Tuples in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have some problem in my database

```
Select * from table where JobId='329188628'
```

**Result:**

```
ID     JobId      ONETID
-----------------------
32951  329188628    532
32951  329188628    532
32951  329188628    532
32951  329188628    532
```

I need to remove the duplicate rows.
can any one please help me ?

Comment: You want to remove from the table or the query result?

Comment: Okay all are fine. what is my need was

Comment: @susanstefan Look at [**this SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a281/1)

Comment: I my table i'm having JobId and ONETID are the duplicate columns. so i want to remove those duplicate. but i need to keep one row of the duplicate one.

Comment: @susanstefan there are 2 answers for this susan. Check techdo's or mine. They both do what you need. I will change mine to have only the 2 if this is what you need. But to remove them that is the way.

Comment: @susanstefan You should accept the answer which is appropriate to you.

Comment: @him056 can you please explain your detele query

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
with c as(
select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by (select 0)) as n
from table where JobID='329188628'
)delete from c
where n > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
with cte(cnt) as
(
  select row_number() over(partition by ID,JobId,ONETID order by getdate())
  from table where JobId='329188628'
)
delete from cte where cnt>1
```

and with only JobId and OnetId for grouping.

```
with cte(cnt) as
(
  select row_number() over(partition by JobId,ONETID order by getdate())
  from table where JobId='329188628'
)
delete from cte where cnt>1
```

Comment: 7 answers, only two answer the question!

Comment: @podiluska, Thats because of the misleading explanation of the OP.

Comment: "I need to remove the duplicate rows" doesn't look too unclear to me

Comment: @podiluska I too agree with you. But his/her `SELECT` query confused us.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
Select DISTINCT * from table where JobId='329188628'
```